# Что конкретно возвращает свойство WriteableBitmap.Pixels (платформа Silverlight)

Tags: c#, silverlight

Что конкретно возвращает свойство [WriteableBitmap.Pixels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixels%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (платформа Silverlight) и как формируются эти значения?

Что уже есть:

```
private int[] GetPixelsIntArray(Bitmap bmp)
{
     int[] pix = new int[bmp.Width * bmp.Height];

     int x, y;
     for (y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
     {
          for (x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
          {
              Color c = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
              pix[y * bmp.Width + x] = c.ToArgb();
          }
      }

      return pix;
    }
```

Comment: Ну там же вроде есть документация. А что неясно?

Comment: @VladD, документация на английском. В переводе - черти что. Если не затруднит - приведите пример кода на основе Bitmap для получения этих значений (int[]). По коду проще понять. Конкретно непонятно как получить список этих значений из Bitmap.   p.s. хотел я уйти от silverlight, не получилось к сожалению. Слишком много на него завязано.

Comment: @VladD, добавил в ответ то, что уже есть. Но незнаю насколько корректен метод. И проверить нет возможности.

Comment: А почему `4 * bmp.Width * bmp.Height`?

Comment: @VladD, поправил.

Comment: Ну так насколько я понимаю, Pixels именно это и возвращает. Только там ещё A-компонента (RGBA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, именно это и возвращает `Pixels`. Исходя из документации, stride не учитывается.

```
var pixels = bmp.Pixels;
Debug.Assert(pixels.Length == bmp.PixelWidth * bmp.PixelHeight);

int idx = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
{
    // argb little endian layout: AARRGGBB
    var value = pixels[idx];
    var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
    byte a = bytes[3]; // кажется, не напутал с порядком индексов
    byte r = bytes[2];
    byte g = bytes[1];
    byte b = bytes[0];
    Console.WriteLine("At ({0}, {1}): rbg = ({2}, {3}, {4}), a = {5}",
                      x, y, r, g, b, a/256.0);
}
```

Обратите внимание, что значения являются предварительно умноженными на alpha. То есть если у вас был красный с alpha = 0.5, вы получите: `a = 0x80`, `r = 0x80` (а не `0xff`), `g = b = 0`.

Если хочется скорости и битовой арифметики, тогда

```
    var value = (uint)pixels[idx];
    byte a = (byte)(value >> 24);
    byte r = (byte)(value >> 16);
    byte g = (byte)(value >>  8);
    byte b = (byte)(value      );
```

(конверсия отбросит старшие биты).